# Autostart Countdown Timer in button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a countdown timer into my page to show when the page will be redirect to google.com. So far i have create a button but it will only start counting when i clicked it. Is it possible to make the button auto start countdown when i access to that page?

```
<button id="myButton" class="butstyle" style="float:right">Click To Redirect</button>


<script>

var counter = 10;
$('.butstyle').on('click',function(e){

e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

if($(this).hasClass('butstyle')){

$('.butstyle').text('You will be redirected in: 10 seconds');
$(this).removeClass().addClass('butAfter');

var int = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    $('.butAfter').text('You will be redirected in: '+counter+' seconds');

    if (counter == 0) {

        clearInterval(int);
        counter = 10;
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
        //do your next action here:

    }
}, 1000);

}

});

 </script>
```

Comment: put relevant code on $(document).ready(function () function

Comment: you have the code running when clicking the button. Have it on load#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch your button on click function with document ready like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Put relevant code here
}
```

Comment: your mean change this $('.butstyle').on('click',function(e){ to $( document ).ready(function() { ??

Comment: Yes, this way your function will be executed when the page is loaded. This way you also don't have to `preventDefault()`

Comment: I had try to change it, but still cannot auto countdown.

Comment: You can put a `console.log("Auto countdown");` in the function to check if it is executed. I think the problem is your `if` because the `this` isn't the button anymore

Comment: After i remove e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); and ($(this).hasClass('butstyle')){ , It can redirect to google.com after 10s, but the button timer did't countdown

Comment: Because the `butAfter`class is not added to your button. You have to select the button via its ID and add the butAfter class.

Comment: Thanks, is my careless

Answer (score 1):

Use this. This will automatically clicks on you button with this part of code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".butAfter").trigger("click");
});
```

And Counter starts.

Final code:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".butAfter", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  if ($(this).hasClass('butstyle')) {

    $('.butstyle').text('You will be redirected in: 10 seconds');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('butAfter');

    var int = setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
      $('.butAfter').text('You will be redirected in: ' + counter + ' seconds');

      if (counter == 0) {

        clearInterval(int);
        counter = 10;
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
        //do your next action here:

      }
    }, 1000);

  }

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".butAfter").trigger("click");
});

var counter = 10;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="myButton" class="butstyle butAfter" style="float:right">Click To Redirect</button>
```